# Rails named scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller, scope

I was trying to refactoring and optimizing me code. In particular, I wanted to reduce the amount of queries going to the database. In my users controller it worked very well but in an other controller, where I tried the same, it didn't. I've searched for some time now for the answer why it didn't work but I can't really answer it.

I've got users, which can subscribe to courses through enrolments. They are connected through  has_many :through etc. relationships. The following works:

```
@users_courses = current_user.courses
@courses = @users_courses.a_named_scope
```

But in my courses controller the following wont work:

```
@all_courses = Course.all
@specific_course = @all_courses.specific_course_scope
```

The scopes are defined in the respective models and work properly. They are not complicated, just "where ... true/false" definitions. Does someone know the problem here? Thanks!

I'm using rails version 3.2 and ruby version 2.

Comment: What version of Rails do you use?

Comment: I use Rails version 3.2 and ruby 2. Sorry I forgot that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until Rails 4 you should use `scoped` method if you want to have `ActiveRecord::Relation` instance (on which you can call other scopes) returned instead of `Array`:

```
@all_courses = Course.scoped
@specific_course = @all_courses.specific_course_scoped
```

This should work.

If you want to use `includes(:courses)`, you just do it, for example with:

```
@specific_course = @all_courses.specific_course_scoped.includes(:courses)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! May I ask what would be different if I would use rails 4? And one more questions, is it possible to combine this with an includes(:courses) statement?

Comment: @LinusAn in Rails 4 `all` returns `ActiveRecord::Relation` and `scoped` method is deprecated. So your code would be good.
I edited my answer to answer your second question.